Direction of Stack Trace in ProcMon
I am trying to understand how to interpret the stack trace in event properties of ProcMon. I know that the stack works on a last in first out basis, however the numbering of the frames in the stack trace is confusing me. Is the first function called at the bottom of the stack i.e. the highest frame number (40) and the latest function at the top of the stack i.e. frame number 0?
Also do the functions call the functions directly above them? Thank you.

